# Can I clone an xml node in place?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, deep-copy

Bit of a newbie to Python and even more so to xml so bear with me:)

I have an existing xml file with a structure as below. I want to clone any `<Zone>` node that matches `<name>.text == "Bill"` or whatever I specify.

I tried looping through and using `elem.append(copy.deepcopy(---))` but I ended up appending nodes that then got added into my loop - needless to say it ran for a while!

Can I do this easily in place or do I have to write everything to another file? I would add code but afraid it is mangled and would just complicate things!

Hope I've made the problem clear.

```
<DBname>  
    <Level_1>  
        <Zone>  
            <name>Fred</name>  
            <att1>xxx</att1>  
            <att2>yyy</att2>  
        </Zone>  
        <Zone>  
            <name>Bill</name>  
            <att1>111</att1>  
            <att2>222</att2>  
        </Zone>  
        <Zone>  
            <name>Bob</name>  
            <att1>333</att1>  
            <att2>444</att2>  
        </Zone>  
    </Level_1>  
</DBname>
```

OK I may have worked out a solution but any comments / improvements most welcome.

This does not work. The appended items stuff up the "for" loop:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root  = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    for source in elem:
        if source.find('name').text == "Bill":
            elem.append(copy.deepcopy(source))
```

This does appear to work:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root  = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    for zone in elem.findall('Zone'):
        if zone.find('name').text == "Bill":
            elem.append(copy.deepcopy(zone))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt looks correct.  The problem is that you're modifying an object while trying to iterate over it.

In the case of `for source in elem`, it appears `lxml` iterates over child nodes lazily, so any new node added before `lxml` reaches the end is included in the iteration.  By using `.findall`, you get a new list of the descendants which isn't affected by subsequent changes to `elem`.

Note that your working code has different semantics now; it will find *all* descendant `Zone` tags, not just children.  Given your schema, this probably doesn't matter, but it's extra work you already know you don't need.

You could fix the first attempt by doing:

```
for source in list(elem):
```

This creates a separate list of child nodes, so modifications to `elem` are safe and won't affect the loop.

And if you want to explicitly restrict the looping to just `Zone`s:

```
for source in list(elem.iter('Zone')):
```

Comment: Thanks Eevee - for the explanation and for the extra code hints as well. I'm learning!